# Wordpress admin subpage metafields

Tags: wordpress

I was just wondering is it possible to move som user metafields to a subpage
So i have 2 subpages one called account and one profile?

I've figured out how to create the subpage but how do i move metafields to that subpage.

Thanks

Comment: You want to display the values of meta fields of *account* on the *profile* page? And *profile* is a child of *account*?

Comment: No i want to create a subpage in the admin bar under profile which i have.
But then i need to move the metaboxes to that subpage.

Comment: I still don't get it, what  is the use of this page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *move* them. You have to hide through CSS and/or jQuery, as there are not much useful hooks in [**`/wp-admin/user-edit.php`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-admin/user-edit.php).

And then replicate the same fields in your custom page, and use the appropriate update function: [`wp_update_user`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user) or [`update_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta).